# How can i get a json from telegram message using telethon (Pyton)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Amr.png)

I'd like to parse strings from message. (not in channel, from user's message). I get a message like this by using this --> print(client.get_messages('bot_name')).

I applicated an image because i want to show you, that i want to get from message.

> [Message(id=177, peer_id=PeerUser(user_id=123456789),
> date=datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 31, 10, 30, 35,
> tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='\n├ Номер: 79991234567\n├
> Страна: Россия\n├ Регион: г.Москва и Московская область\n└ Оператор:
> Билайн\n\n Возможные имена:\n└  Джек и еще 6 имен\n\n ФИО:
> найдено\n Возможные адреса: найдено\n Вконтакте: найдено\n Дата
> рождения: найдено\n\u200d♂️ Facebook:  найдено\n Telegram:
> найдено\n✅ Whatsapp: есть\n✅ Viber: есть\n Объявлений: 26
> шт\n\u200d♂️ Интересовались: 2 человека\n Репутация: (0) (0)
> \n\n⚠️ Для просмотра результатов поиска необходимо приобрести
> подписку!\nℹ️ Если информация не найдена, закажите «Расширенный
> поиск»', out=False, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False,
> post=False, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, edit_hide=False,
> pinned=False, from_id=None, fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None,
> reply_to=None, media=None,
> reply_markup=ReplyInlineMarkup(rows=[KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='
> Оформить подписку', data=b'PREMIUM|welcome',
> requires_password=False)]),
> KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text=' Расширенный
> поиск - 30₽', data=b'PREMIUM|PHONE|79991234567',
> requires_password=False)]),
> KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text=' Добавить
> репутацию', data=b'REP|0|79991234567', requires_password=False)]),
> KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonUrl(text='✅ Whatsapp',
> url='https://botapi.co/whatsapp/79991234567?&gclid=18547829:695de1f0395e3a1a2496bbc02629c1c6&_bk=cloudflare'),
> KeyboardButtonUrl(text=' Viber',
> url='https://botapi.co/viber/79991234567?&gclid=18547829:695de1f0395e3a1a2496bbc02629c1c6&_bk=cloudflare')])]),
> entities=[MessageEntityBold(offset=5, length=6),
> MessageEntityCode(offset=12, length=11), MessageEntityBold(offset=26,
> length=7), MessageEntityBold(offset=43, length=7),
> MessageEntityBold(offset=83, length=9), MessageEntityBold(offset=104,
> length=16), MessageEntityBold(offset=124, length=6),
> MessageEntityItalic(offset=131, length=12),
> MessageEntityBold(offset=148, length=4), MessageEntityCode(offset=153,
> length=7), MessageEntityBold(offset=164, length=17),
> MessageEntityCode(offset=182, length=7), MessageEntityBold(offset=193,
> length=10), MessageEntityCode(offset=204, length=7),
> MessageEntityBold(offset=215, length=14),
> MessageEntityCode(offset=230, length=7), MessageEntityBold(offset=244,
> length=9), MessageEntityCode(offset=255, length=7),
> MessageEntityBold(offset=266, length=9), MessageEntityCode(offset=276,
> length=7), MessageEntityBold(offset=286, length=9),
> MessageEntityCode(offset=296, length=4), MessageEntityBold(offset=303,
> length=6), MessageEntityCode(offset=310, length=4),
> MessageEntityBold(offset=318, length=11),
> MessageEntityCode(offset=330, length=5), MessageEntityBold(offset=342,
> length=15), MessageEntityCode(offset=358, length=10),
> MessageEntityBold(offset=372, length=10),
> MessageEntityCode(offset=384, length=1), MessageEntityCode(offset=390,
> length=1), MessageEntityBold(offset=400, length=64),
> MessageEntityBold(offset=468, length=4), MessageEntityBold(offset=505,
> length=19)], views=None, forwards=None, replies=None, edit_date=None,
> post_author=None, grouped_id=None, restriction_reason=[],
> ttl_period=None), total=35][enter image description here]

Comment: Please remove the `python-telegram-bot` tag, which is for a different library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in [Telethon's FAQ](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-field):

```py
async def main():
    messages = await client.get_messages('bot_name')
    # messages is a list. you can access it by index as with any other list in python

    message = messages[0]
    # message is a Message object. you can access its .text property as with any other object in python

    print(message.raw_text)  # raw_text for no formatting

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

You may also read about other [`Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#module-telethon.tl.custom.message) fields and properties.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It helped me.
If i want to get these fields from a message like keys and values, is it possible? I just don't see a json construction.

Comment: You can either use `getattr(message, 'text')` or `d = message.to_dict(); d['message']`, however, most of the time, this is unnecessary.